# keep specific inner class in android proguard

Tags: java, android, proguard, inner-classes

how can i keep inner class in android when use proguard.

i have a class

```java
class A{
  public void setXX(B b){}
  public interface B{ }
}
```

when i use prouard in android it will become

```java
class A{
  public void setXX(A$B b){}
}
```

B will become A$B too,how can i keep it the same as
`public void setXX(B b){}`

in the proguard files ,i set as follow:

```
-keep class A$* {
    *;
}
-keep class A$B {
    *;
}
```

and when i use
`-keepattributes InnerClasses` ,it worked ,but it will keep all the inner classes,how can i keep only the specific inner class ?

Answer (score 0):

**try this**

using `@Keep` annotation

```
 @Keep
    class A{       
        //inner class
        @Keep
        class B{
        }
    }
```